# Django obtener info en la misma pagina sin mostar el pk en la url

Tags: python, django

espero puedan ayudarme, estoy tratando de ver información de la base de datos pero sin mover la url.

Cuando accedo a lista obtendo por ejemplo una lista de libros y cuando hago clic accedo a detalle en donde están los detalles del libro, sin embargo cuando entro en esa pagina ella url tiene el id de la base de datos del modelo.

¿Existe alguna manera de poder acceder sin que se mueva la url?

Espero puedan ayudarme o darme algunos ejemplos

urls:

```
url(r'^detalle/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.detalle_id, name="detalle_id"),
url(r'^detalle/(?P<nombre>.*)/$', views.detalle_nombre),
```

views:

```
def detalle_id(request, pk):
    detalle = Pregunta.objects.get(pk=pk)
    Pregunta.objects.filter(id=pk).update(comentario='1')

    return render(request, 'detalle.html', {'detalle': detalle})


def detalle_nombre(request, nombre):
    detalle = Pregunta.objects.get(nombre=nombre)
    return render(request, 'detalle.html', {'detalle': detalle})

def lista(request):
    listadb = Pregunta.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'lista.html', {'listadb':listadb})
```

Espero puedan ayudarme o darme algunos ejemplos, Gracias!

Comment: Rodrigo a que te refieres con que no quieres mover la URL? Lo que quieres es acceder a la vista detalle de un objeto sin que la id salga en la URL?

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurren dos opciones:

1. Enviar el `id` usando el verbo `POST`. Y en lugar de un enlace, usar un botón, y obvio, procesar el formulario

   ```
   <form method='POST' action='{% url "detalle_id" '>
       {% csrf_token %}
       <input type='hidden' value='{{ detalle.id }}' name='id'>
       <input type="submit" name='Botón de enviar' value="Ver detalle">
   </form>
   ```
2. Usar jQuery para traer la información, por ejemplo

   ```
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: {% url 'detalle_id' %},
     dataType: "html",
     success: // lo que hagas con tus datos
   });
   ```